# The email automatically sent to the signer after the envelope is signed is not in English

Tags: docusignapi

The email automatically sent to the signer after the envelope is signed is not in English. All other emails are sent according to the language set by my system account. This email is not in English. Where should this email be configured? The corresponding interface and language parameters were not found in the API.

Comment: Does this happen no matter who the signer is? if you try different singers (emails) than you still get this other language? Im asking cause it's possible the signer/user configured that they wish a different lang which is different user/account from the person who sent the envelope

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether or not the signer has an existing DocuSign membership  -- some elements related to recipient language you can control, others persist through the recipient's browser session or selected language.

I put a blog post on the different scenarios available on our DevCenter a whie back -- have a look at https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/the-trenches-recipient-email-languages

Basically, you have some control over what language the recipient sees if they have not previously signed. If they have and have adopted a language or set the browser session to another language, there isn't much you can do as the sender.

Feel free to reach out to our support line to discuss if you have additional questions, happy to run through this with you in realtime.